# Убрать знак Аналитик

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

В списке знаков ruSO и ruSO Мета есть знак Аналитик

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/77/analytical

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/77/analytical

Этот знак никто никогда не получал и никогда не получит, потому не вижу нужды в нём

Предлагаю только у нас убрать этот знак

###### UPD

Насколько я понял, [список знаков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) одинаковый везде и очень много вероятно, что не согласятся для нас делать исключение и убрать только у нас. Тем более что на других сайтах есть и по 2 знака, которые никто не получал и никогда не получит. Например [тут](https://aviation.stackexchange.com)  на сайте [Аналитик](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/77/analytical) и [Реверс](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/reversal)

Потому было бы логично придумать общее правило для всех сайтов без исключения. Как вариант предлагали сделать общую проверку:

> Если знак устарел и никто его так и не получил за всё время, то не показывать этот знак

Как по мне это очень простое и элегантное решение, так что я за такую проверку на всех сайтах

Comment: Не мешает же никому - пусть болтается.

Comment: @Qwertiy Не нужна же никому - пусть не болтается :)

Comment: Я не совсем понял как его получить)) может быть сделать это?))

Comment: аааа. "и более не присуждается." .... ясно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ты успел прочитать... А я вот увидел что его никто не получал и решил первым его получить и запустить челлендж небольшой и не прочитал что "более не присуждается". Потратил 15 минут, переходя по всем ссылкам "Я не совсем понял как его получить" - просто надо зайти во все вопросы отмеченные как `faq`))

Comment: @EzioMercer, откуда информация, что нужно читать именно вопросы с меткой faq, а не какой-то раздел справки, которого просто уже нет? В английском варианте речь идет про секции чего-то, значит явно не вопросы: [Visited every section of the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1306/analytical)

Comment: @insolor "Visited every section of the FAQ" - Ну я это понял как то что надо перейти по всем сслыкам в разделе FAQ, а там я не помню, чтобы были ссылки на не FAQ вопросы, потому и решил, что если пройтись по всем вопросам с меткой FAQ, то точно посещу все разделы из FAQ. Ну собственно это то почему я так сказал, если же у нас в FAQ-е есть ссылки на вопросы, которые не помечены тегом FAQ, то тогда я неправильно предположил

Comment: [старая история](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291119/339911)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ "But if it's a "closed" badge and nobody already has it, there's no benefit to including it on the list" - Я правильно понял, что знак, который никому не присуждён и более не может быть присуждён, не должен быть на сайте? Т.е. этот знак давно должен был пропасть по сути, да?

Comment: это просто мнение бывшего модератора, оно мало что значит

Answer (score -1):

Я против. Измените их смысл, например:
Аналитик: серебрянный, ознакомиться со всеми популярными метками(иметь 5 рейтинга по ним).
Реверс можно убрать, у него есть замена.

Comment: Нельзя менять описание/задачи/смысл знаков. Есть куча людей на других сайтах, которые получили тот или иной знак им что тогда по новой получать этот знак? Список для всех одиноковый, потому нужные общие правила для всех сайтов